# Does REST supports protocol buffers

Tags: rest, protocol-buffers

This might be a very generic question, but considering the fact that REST is focused on accessing named resources through a single consistent interface; does it supports protocol buffers?

Comment: PB is ultimately just a data format. As far as REST is concerned, resource representations can be sent in any data format negotiated between server an client. There's nothing in the "RESTful equation" that says one data format is more RESTful than a different data format.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending protocol buffers via REST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3187270/sending-protocol-buffers-via-rest)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Yes, you can absolutely combine Protobuf and REST.

Protbuf specifies a way to encode data. REST specifies a way to interact with resources, but does not require any particular encoding for the resource bodies. If you create a RESTful HTTP-based API and use Protobuf to encode the entity-bodies (the technical term for the payload part of an HTTP request or response), then you are using both REST and Protobuf.

Comment: Can you please provide a code sample to demonstrate how to send a protobuf message to a REST POST service using REST Easy Client? I am trying to find an answer for the same and have not found anything helpful so far.

Comment: @BibekKr.Bazaz Sorry, I'm not familiar with "REST Easy Client".

Comment: Hi Kenton, I have actually found the solution. I have followed the tutorial at the following link.  [https://javarants.com/using-jax-rs-with-protocol-buffers-for-high-performance-rest-apis-563ce40d15d9] I have used Jersey Client for the same instaed of RestEasy client but the idea should be similar. At the Service we need to write consumes=application\x-protobuf for the post service. Also from the client side, we need to provide the protobuff readers and writers to send protobuf over rest. These readers and writers basically convert the protobuff to input/output Stream.

Answer (score -2):

Back to the future, there is this [Spring REST API with Protocol Buffers](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-api-with-protocol-buffers) tutorial:

Generate the corresponding Java classes using:

`protoc --java_out=java resources/baeldung.proto`

Add the following dependency on your Maven's POM file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
    <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-beta-3</version>
</dependency>
```

Add the following converter to your @SpringBootApplication:

```
@Bean
ProtobufHttpMessageConverter protobufHttpMessageConverter() {
    return new ProtobufHttpMessageConverter();
}
```

The ProtobufHttpMessageConverter bean is used to convert responses returned by @RequestMapping annotated methods to protocol buffer messages.

What's important here is that we're operating with Protocol Buffer specific data – not with standard POJOs.